# Issue with "less" filter

Tags: css, symfony, less

I'm founding the compile of templates with "less" is not working properly (the css compiling doesn't work as expected) when I have too much content in my less file.

The compiling problems are with the content that are compiled at the end of the less file, in fact if I remove temporarily the content of the beginning of the file, the content at the end is compiled ok.

I have tried to compile the file from the less command line and I don't have those problems.

I'm thinking in some lack of memory as the origin of the problem...

Any idea?

Assetic 1.0.1/less 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [solved](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/108) my problems.